# SSAS Design 2 Fact tables (1 Weekly, 1 Monthly)

Tags: ssrs, facttable

I am currently busy building a sales cube for a customer. However they would also like to see their current stock count in the same cube. The Sales Fact table is on a daily grain, where as the Stock Fact is aggregated on a weekly grain. They would like to see their stock as at sales date. I know i will need to add a calculated field, i am just not sure how to create this. For instance, they close business on a Sunday, so as from Monday, I need to subtract total sales from the Closed Sunday Stock and so forth for each day until Sunday again.

Comment: Welcome to DBA.SE!  While the question is pretty clear, it's still difficult to answer because we don't have appropriate context yet (e.g. your table structure, etc.).  I would suggest [editing your question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/posts/247406/edit) with a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) after which you will likely get some better answers, likely including the code you need as well.